# How to append text to plain text inside of Foundation menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I am trying to reach inside of my foundation menu and append a span to some of the menu items if they have submenus but I can't figure out how to reach the text. Is there a way to get the to the text using jQuery so I can append an icon on it? I want to reach the "Products" text but I don't know how to target it.
[image]

Comment: So you want to append an icon to the link? or as part of it's text, where "Products" is the text?

Comment: I want to append icon text. Basically just want an arrow (>) after it so that I can change it from a right facing arrow to a down arrow once the menu is opened up

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML in the question, along with your own attempt(s) at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://api.jquery.com/text/ :

```
// I don't know what selector you should use, so don't copy this exactly.
var element = $('#my-element');
var text = element.text();
element.text(text + '>');
```

Make sure `element` is the element with the text and not its parent, otherwise I think you'll lose the link.

If you have a jquery object containing lots of elements and you want to do this for all of them, then you can use https://api.jquery.com/each/ to run the above code for each element, by setting `var element = $(this);`.